# validate form without refreshing page and showing error through validationEngine

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-validation-engine

I'm using in the same page a validation engine with date picker.

- Datepicker: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/
- Validationengine: http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html

I've added a `jQuery.noConflict();` to make it work (at the beginning of the code).

Now, I need to make my insert through a PHP file, but without refreshing the page, and by displaying an error message in the same bubble of validationEngine (for example when the email  is already registered in the BDD).

1. should I import jQuery to make my insert in the same page
   without causing conflicts, or can I use one on the query already used
   for the same purpose?
2. How do I display a server response through the validationEngine?

My code is the following one.

```js
$(".btn_newsletter").live('click', function() { 
  $.ajax(
    {
      url: "php/functions/signin.php"+nomfichier,
      success: function(data) { 
        if (data.check==0) {alert('Error : Sorry '); return false;}
        if (data.check==1) {alert('yep!!!');                                                                            
      }
    },
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json'
  });
}
```

This is my PHP code.

```php
  $ip= $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
  $select = "select * from av_newsletter where email='".$_POST['email']."'";
  $exist = $_BASE->query_array($select);
  if ($exist) { 
    $check = "0";
  }
  else {
    $ajout="INSERT INTO av_newsletter(id,sub_date,email,ip) VALUES (NULL,now(),'$email','$ip')";
    $add=$_BASE->query($ajout);
    if ($add) { 
      $check="1";  
    }
  }

  $return_arr["check"] = $check;
  echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

It doesn't work; I've no alert, but also no errors.

Comment: Make a priority list of all the things you want the form to do, e.g. username, email etc already taken. Create a PHP script to validate this (check against database) and return a JSON response like {'username':'free', 'email':'taken'}, process that in your form for notifications.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i've added the code above, Doesn't work i've no alert, but also no error :/

Comment: put a console.log(data) before the first if(data.check==0), and I believe the 0 will be a string "0". Also use tools like firebug in firefox to see the results without the need to debug the responses in the javascript files all the time

Comment: still no result, no error, (no insert also):/ i think there is a problem with the variable data which not contain the answer of signin.php, i can't understand why :/
Thanks again.
console.log(data); 
if(data.check=='0'){  alert('Error : Sorry '); return false; }          if(data.check=='1'){  alert('yep!!!');                     
}

Comment: You should see something response in console, probably because you are not using any console ;) Change console.log(data) into alert(data); Also add an alert('testing1234') before $.ajax to see if the click get's executed

Comment: oh thanks,i see in the consol! 
"data is not defined" 
hmm the question is how to catch  signin.php answer ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not tied in too deeply to your 'Validationengine' I would recommend using [this](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) one, is has served me well for years, it has support for making remote checks so you could do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var save_options = {
    success:        userSaved, //callback function
    url:           '/users/save',
    response:      'json',
    method:        'post'
};

var validationObj = {
    rules: {
        name: "required",
        email: {
        email: true,
            required: true,
            remote: "/user/check_email/"
        }
    },
    messages: {
        name: "Please name yourself",
        email: {
            required: "Please enter your email address",
            email: "Invalid email address",
            remote: "Email already in use."
        }
    },
    errorPlacement:function(error, element) {
        error.appendTo( element.next() );
    },
    submitHandler:  function(form) {
        $(form).ajaxSubmit(save_options);
    },
    success:function(label) {
        label.html("&nbsp;").addClass("checked");
    }
};
```

});

And then on the PHP side at the '/users/check_email' endpoint the PHP does the following:

```
echo $emailExists ? json_encode(false) : json_encode(true);
```

Comment: oh thanks, that seems to be interesting and simplier, in my case i need to continue with validationengine :/
I'm sure that i'll use this in the future instead validationengine!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, before we spam the comments and get to far off topic, please execute this code which should get you started in getting it to work eventually.

```
$(".btn_newsletter").live('click',function() {
  alert('clicked'); // click is executed
  $.ajax({                           
    url: "php/functions/signin.php"+nomfichier,
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data); // should alert the data
      if(data.check==0){  alert('Error : Sorry '); return false; }
      if(data.check==1){  alert('yep!!!'); }                                                                    
    },
    error: function(request, status, error) {
      alert('failed '+status);
    },
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json'
  });
});
```

Comment: so i've the alert "clicked" but not alert about data, this is why i've not any insert :/

Comment: try again with updated code above, added an error callback, most likely the nomfichier variable does not exist, and your url will result in `php/functions/signin.phpundefined`

Comment: the url is right, i've deleted this variable "nomfichier"
I asked my self is there any jquery that miss to make $.ajax works?

Comment: It should work this way, there is no reason to believe that the jQuery click event gets executed, and everything inside the callback for click doesn't. If the success, nor the error function get's triggered, then there must be something else, check the error console when clicking the button.

Comment: i see, it almost work, the only problem is that in my signin.php the $_POST['email'] is empty, it has register one time email="" (empty) and for the others i'd a fail because empty field email exist already in my DB.
I don't see why my POST is empty , should i catch the value of input in the Jquery instead of sumbitting it with form??
(ps: the problem wad in my sql rquest, so that's why i didn't see anything, thank you again)

Comment: because it is not sending any dating, you have to use the option data : {'email', 'some@email.com}, I don't know where you can retrieve this data because there is no HTML to lookup where you might retrieve this info

Answer (score 0):

it works :)

```
    $(".btn_newsletter").live('click',function() {
              var data ="email="+$('#email').val();

  $.ajax({                           
    url: "php/functions/signin.php"+"?"+data,
    success: function(data) {   
          if(data.check=='1'){  alert('yep!!!'); }                                                                    
          if(data.check=='0'){  alert('Error : Sorry '); return false; }
    },
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json'
  });
});
```

and in my signin.php I catch the value of the input like this `$email=$_REQUEST['email']`
Thanks a lot! time for me to see about validation engine how to link this with :)